# Cannot Setup SOCKS Proxy with Firefoxdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a problem with SOCKS5 proxy with firefox driver in Java.

```
    final FirefoxOptions FIREFOX_OPTIONS = new FirefoxOptions();
    final Proxy PROXY = new Proxy().setProxyType(Proxy.ProxyType.MANUAL).setSocksVersion(5).setSocksProxy
            ("host:port");

    FIREFOX_OPTIONS.setHeadless(true);

    desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, PROXY);

    webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(FIREFOX_OPTIONS.merge(desiredCapabilities));`
```

After starting session I receive this error message.

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

Without setCapability, firefox driver seems working fine, but without proxy connection.

```
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, PROXY);
```

Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 0):

It might be something like:

```
FIREFOX_OPTIONS.addArguments(--firefox.preference "network.proxy.socks:host" + ":" + --firefox.preference "network.proxy.socks_port:port");
```

The syntax may be incorrect because I'm not familiar with firefox or java but I believe the arguments may have to be added. In chrome it is:

```
.addArguments("--proxy-server=socks5://" + host + ":" + port);
```